# Why can public inline functions call private constructors

Tags: kotlin

I have a private constructor for my class and implemented invoke on the companion object for some kind of "generic constructor"

```
class Test private constructor(className: String) {
    companion object {
        // If I remove the internal it fails 
        internal inline operator fun <reified T> invoke(): Test {
            return Test(T::class.java.name) // why can I even call it? The constructor is private
        }
    }
}
```

and I can even have a public inline function that calls that generic constructor

```
public inline fun test() = Test<Any>() // Why can I call it, it is internal
```

shouldn't that mean that every invokation `test()` expands to `Test(Any::class.java.name)` even though that constructor is private?

So my questions are:

- Why can that `internal inline fun` call a private constructor? (a public fun couldn't)
- Why can that `public inline fun` call an internal function?
- And why can I ultimately expose a private constructor in a `public inline fun`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Why can that internal inline fun call a private constructor? (a public fun couldn't)

An **`internal`** `inline` function can access non-public API, because it can only be called in the same module, and thus it won't suffer from binary incompatibility that might be introduced when the API changes and the calling module is not re-compiled (see the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#public-inline-restrictions)). Such calls are only prohibited for public API `inline` functions.

> - Why can that public inline fun call an internal function?

It's a bug. Normally, a public `inline` function cannot access non-public API. This rule seems not to be checked for the `invoke()` operator calls. I've submitted the issue: [KT-20223](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20223).

> - And why can I ultimately expose a private constructor in a public inline fun?

That's due to the composition of the expected behavior in the first point and the bug in the second point. Ultimately, it's also a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The companion object is within the class.  So the code within the class is providing an interface to call the private method, but remember this code is code within the class.

Just as public class methods can access private variables and return their values to the outside, these methods can do this because they are part of the class.  The same principle applies in this case, so I suggest this ability to access private members from within the class is to be expected, and behaviour that is less expected is the behaviour of regular inline functions of a class.  I believe the behaviour of regular inline functions in this respect is an implementation restriction that simply is not necessary from the companion object.

Comment: That does not apply for inline functions

Comment: Very true, but I see this as a restriction of the JVM rather than a design choice,  given that normal functions do have such access.   My point is that this ability to access is more inline with what would be expected rather than being a problem.